# How to deal with users who signed up before Mixpanel alias was set up?

Tags: mixpanel

How do you deal with users who had created accounts before Mixpanel alias was set up on signup?

Will there be issues with connecting distinct_id to email b/c alias was never called on signup?

Answer (score 0):

In our project for all new users we write additional parameter in cookies which tells us that this user was registered after Mixpanel alias set up.

And we added additional script on the main and login pages.
If user logs in and the parameter tells us that he was registered before Mixpanel alias - we fire alias + identify to create his profile in Mixpanel and write up-to-date info into his profile in mixpanel.